# shaped jdialog for transparency effect causing dragging issue

Tags: java, macos, swing, transparency, jdialog

I have created shaped JDialog by adding transparency effect by
**setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);** but it also adding drag listener to the dialog internally, problem is, when we drag by any other component in the dialog such as JTextfield, JList etc,. still the complete window is able to drag. so need to avoid adding internal drag listener to the jdialog. please anybody help me regarding this, here is my code.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MyWindow extends JDialog {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyWindow() {
        JTextField text = new JTextField();
        BufferedImage myPicture = null;
        try {
            myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("background.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
        setUndecorated(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));   // creating issue
        setSize(243, 474);
        text.setBounds(18, 64, 212, 368);
        add(text);
        add(label);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MyWindow win = new MyWindow();
                win.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Regards, 
Bharath SR

Comment: Do you just want to be able to drag the dialog from any initial point, except when the mouse drag starts from a component inside the dialog? I may not be understanding your question correctly

Comment: Yes, absolutely.. I don't want to drag the transparent jdialog from starting point of any other components which are in the main jdialog.. if i press the components (which are added to jdialog) and drag, it shouldn't drag.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand your requirements or even your problem, but it sounds like you want a draggable dialog with no frame, just a background image and a component, and you don't want the components to trigger the drag event.

Give this a try. Hopefully it's what you're looking for. Feel free to ask questions.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DragDialog extends JDialog {

    private int pointX;
    private int pointY;

    public DragDialog() {
        JLabel backgroundLabel = createBackgroundLabel();
        JTextField textField = createTextField();
        setContentPane(backgroundLabel);
        add(textField);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private JTextField createTextField() {
        final JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
        field.setText("Type \"exit\" to terminate.");
        field.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String text = field.getText();
                if ("exit".equalsIgnoreCase(text)) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        });
        return field;
    }

    private JLabel createBackgroundLabel() {
        Image image = null;
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://satyajit.ranjeev.in/images/icons/stackoverflow.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DragDialog.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        label.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        label.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                DragDialog.this.setLocation(DragDialog.this.getLocation().x + e.getX() - pointX,
                        DragDialog.this.getLocation().y + e.getY() - pointY);
            }
        });
        label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                pointX = e.getX();
                pointY = e.getY();
            }
        });

        return label;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new DragDialog();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried with your code, but my requirement is add any image to the jdialog and make it transparent by setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0); now add any components like jtextfield or jlist or jbutton. and don't add any drag listener.. but when you drag the window by pressing any of the component, its able to drag.. but it shouldn't drag by component (press hold and drag).. unfortunately its dragging.. if you remove setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0); then its working perfectly but transparency is not adding to the jdialog.. i hope u understood my requirement, and thanks for your valuable reply.

Comment: With my example, the dialog _doesn't_ drag when you try to drag by components.

Comment: Ohh.. I'm sorry to say this. Its working for MicroSoft windows machine, but its not working in mac machine. (issue is coming what I told), it may be the mac platform dependent..